# XCode 7 Date picker cause crash of application

Tags: ios, xcode7

Hi I need to integrate date picker with inputView, I am on Xcode7. Using below code the application cause exception. The exception happening while I am touching UITextField element.

Here is the relevant part of the code where the date picker used.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *graphDate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fromdate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *toDate;
............................................................
..............................................................

[_graphDate setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];

............................................................
..............................................................

[_graphDate setHidden:TRUE];
[_graphDate setFrame:CGRectMake(600, 600, 400, 162)];
_toDate.inputView = _graphDate;
_fromdate.inputView = _graphDate;
_graphDate.date = [NSDate date];
```

The exception message,

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason:
 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x80286850>
 should have parent view controller:<VALiveViewController: 0x7cbeda00>
 but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x7cc25a00>'
```

I already refereed the answer here [UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency in 64 bit iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744059/uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistency-in-64-bit-ios-device) but no idea how to apply here, I am newbie in IOS.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Haris

Comment: did u enable the exception breakpoint and see where it hits while crash?

Comment: I'm wondering how picker is related to the crash!!! DO you have any code related to adding child view controller ?

Comment: The  exception break point showing on main().

Comment: The exception happening while I am touching on `UITextField`

Comment: put a breakpoint on textfield delegate methods, and see if it hits any of them before crashing ?

Comment: try to put a breakpoint on textFieldShouldBeginEditing and see if it hits when u touch the textfield

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will let you know the result.

Comment: Yes IT hitting on the delegate method before crash , here is the code - `(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        
        [_graphDate setHidden:FALSE];
    }`

Comment: did u move the breakpoint between those lines, to see where it crashes?

Comment: Yest it executing the entire function without exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97082/discussion-between-haris-and-mr-t).