# Child view controller should have parent view controller but actual parent is (UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency)

Tags: swift, crash, uinavigationcontroller, childviewcontroller, view-hierarchy

I have an app which has UITabbarController as the initial window(after logging-in i set it as rootViewController)

This tabbarController has 4 different tabs in it which are all UIViewControllers embedded in a UINavigationController.

In my tabbarController when i am making the initial configurations i set tabs like below:

- First I create the viewControllers:

  ```
  let tableViewController1 = tableViewController1(nibName: "tableViewController1", bundle: nil)
  let tableViewController2 = tableViewController2(nibName: "tableViewController2", bundle: nil)
  let tableViewController3 = tableViewController3(nibName: "tableViewController3", bundle: nil)
  let profileViewController = ProfileViewController(nibName: "ProfileViewController", bundle: nil)
  ```
- Then I embed them inside navigationControllers:

  ```
  let navController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableViewController1)
  let navController2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableViewController2)
  let navController3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableViewController3)
  let navController4 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profileViewController)
  ```
- Finally, add the navigationControllers as tabbarController's viewControllers

  viewControllers = [navController1,navController2,navController3,navController4]

I looked it up online and this way of using it seems correct. Ex: https://medium.com/@ITZDERR/uinavigationcontroller-and-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically-swift-3-d85a885a5fd0. However i'm receiving crash logs from my live app as below

```
Crash, child view controller:<UINavigationController: 0x160b3400>
should have parent view controller:<ProfileViewController: 0x16098800>
but actual parent is:<MyApp.MainTabBarController: 0x16064c00>
```

The problem in here is that the crash says profileViewController should be the parent of the navigationController however i embedded profileViewController inside the navigationController and added as tabbarController's viewControllers, so in my opinion the order is correct.

I searched for this crash and it seems like i'm skipping a step of either  using addChildViewController or removing a parent somewhere, but couldn't figured out.

I have find related link to this but non-of them helped me to solve this issue.

Example links:

- http://www.iriphon.com/2012/03/31/uncaught-exception-uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistency-reason-child-view-controller-should-have-parent-view-controller-but-actual-parent-is-or-apples-new-uiviewcontroller-hierarc/
- [UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency in 64 bit iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744059/uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistency-in-64-bit-ios-device)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having similar problems

Comment: I did solve it, however it's been so long that i do not remember how :_) At least i can make a suggestion which may fix the issue. I have added a 0.1 sec time delay which if i remember correctly fixed it. Hope it becomes useful :)

Comment: Ah the delay thingy - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue, and adding `layoutifneeded()` worked for me. example below:

```
navigationController.setViewControllers([], animated: false)
navigationController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

The problem is the `navigaionController` doesn't remove `viewControllers` immediately.
`layoutifneeded` tells the system to redraw immediately. So the crash won't happen.